# How I can rename a date column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working with a little dataframe it has a column with dates. I'm trying to rename the column but I get de following error: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`, anyone knows what am I doing wrong?
The code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

inicio = datetime(2017,10,1)
fin    = datetime(2017,10,5)


lista_fechas = [(inicio + timedelta(days=d)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    for d in range((fin - inicio).days + 1)] 
print(lista_fechas)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=lista_fechas)
df1 = df.rename(columns=['0', 'Fecha'])
```

Comment: use a dictionary, mapping the old name to the new one : ``df.rename(columns = {0:'Fecha'})``

Answer (score 1):

`rename` can't be used like that, why not just use:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

inicio = datetime(2017,10,1)
fin    = datetime(2017,10,5)


lista_fechas = [(inicio + timedelta(days=d)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    for d in range((fin - inicio).days + 1)] 
print(lista_fechas)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=lista_fechas, columns=['Fecha'])
```

If you still want to use `rename` try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=lista_fechas, columns=['Fecha'])
df1 = df.rename(columns = {0:'Fecha'})
```

Comment: I think this not what OP wants, If you want that way, it would be `df = pd.DataFrame(data=lista_fechas, columns=['Fecha'])`

Comment: @Epsi95 True, edited my answer